# How to export points coordinates in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I drew a map of a floor with illustrator. I plan to export this map as .svg and use it in a website, no issue with that. However I would like to place points inside the map that do not represent anything but act as markers that can be used easily while manipulating the svg afterward (for example something that can add a special attribute to the svg path element). Do you have any idea to do it?

Comment: SVG *is* just a list of coordinates

Comment: Also I'm a bit confused on what you're trying to do. If you want to apply an attribute to a path you just use that path, why do you need another point as reference?

Comment: Your SVG code will contain <g> and <path> tags that you can attach classes or IDs to style to your liking.

Comment: Are you trying to make a graph network out of this data so that you can do route planning? You can place invisible data, either dont fill or stroke the data or make it have some outrageous color than just make that style invisible (just remember to export styles)

Comment: Yes joojaa. However I would like to be able to identify them once exported while reading the SVG.

Comment: @Kowalsy well personally i just wrote a com bridge to take the data directly from illustrator as i dont have to parse svg paths but yes you get the id info as css class assignment and groups have names as you have seen. But i deprecated the 2D mapping 3 years ago in favour of doing it in 3D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally found a solution: just name the layers and groups as you like and while exporting illustrator will set the id attribute of the  elements to the names you provided.

Illustrator:

[image]

Exported svg:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Adjust your vector: Object/artboards/convert to artboards
after save as SVG ,SVG option you see SVG code... and save SVG1.1

Comment: How does this answer the question? You are just explaining how to save as SVG, which the question clearly says there is no issue with.